# Why have I never been able to kill a smoker that has grabbed me?

Tags: left-4-dead-2, left-4-dead

I've racked up multiple thousands of hours on left4dead 1 & 2. But one thing that eludes me all of this time, is that I have never, ever, been able to shoot a smoker that has grabbed me in versus and kill it before it's too late, unless the smoker is already injured.

Smoker grabs me, I instantly spin around and start shooting. Regardless of gun, it never does enough damage to kill it before I lose control. Like not, sometimes, or usually, but literally I've never once been able to do this with a full HP smoker.

Yet when playing versus, this FREQUENTLY happens to me, and if a player can do it, they can do it every time you grab them. All they do is aim at me and shoot, sometimes with an AK or with a shotgun, or whatever, and I die. But when I do exactly the same thing, they always, always survive.

In the last game, I grabbed someone quite far away, and despite them having the shotgun, they still were able to kill me. The console showed they hit me 6 times for 264 damage iirc.

Is it something to do with bullet reg? Am I aiming wrong, or timing things wrong? Keep in mind I've never done this even by mistake. Could it be something else?

I've been dying to know why for such a long time.

Comment: Could it be server differences/latency? Some players may have certain settings which could give them more time to retaliate or something; thinking something similar to TF2 Interp.

I don't know anything about L4D at a detailed level though, just a thought that came to mind.

Comment: I have 3,500 hours in LFD2 and have never been shot as or shot a smoker while being dragged. I've freed myself with melee if grabbed too close, but that's quite rare. Granted, I haven't played since 2015, but I doubt it's been updated since then.

Comment: I suspect it might have something to do with interp, there are some articles about it, but I can't find anything definitive. I tried using some settings that were suggested on a forum post, but they just made the game really laggy and unplayable. Perhaps there's a way to tweak those values.